# Error In Binding server Socket: : Address already in use. UDP C programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have problem with creating a second socket

This is part of the code

```
int serverSock;
int clientSock ,newSock;
struct sockaddr_in clientInfo ;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct addrinfo;
int serverPort;
int sockLength;
char destIP[MAXSIZE];
int destPort;
```

The error is happening in this function specifically in bind

```
int createSocket(int port){
    sockLength=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // get struct size
    if(( serverSock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) ==-1) // create the socket
        perror("\nError in Creating socket ");

    memset(&server,0, sizeof(server)); // initialize the socket information
    server.sin_family=AF_INET; // ipv4
    server.sin_port=htons(port); //server port
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY; //server IP
    bzero(&server.sin_zero,8);

    if ((bind(serverSock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)))==-1) // bind the socket with the information
        perror("\nError In Binding server Socket: ");

}

void main(int args, char * argv[]){

    serverPort=atoi(argv[1]);
    createSocket(serverPort); // creating the main Server socket

    printf("%s","Server Is Wating For connections....\n");
    int chkRcv=1;
    struct packet pktToSend;
    struct frame rcvFrm ,frmToSend;
    int ports[]={25011,104002,110003,105004,100705}; // array of ports;
    int portsPtr=0;


    while(1){ // while connection is ok
    printf("Server is listening to %i \n",serverSock);
        if((chkRcv=recvfrom(serverSock ,&rcvFrm,sizeof(rcvFrm),0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientInfo, &sockLength))== 0){ // receive from client
            perror("Client Disconnected......\n");               
            //break;
        }
        strcpy(destIP,rcvFrm.sourceIP);//getClietn IP
        destPort=rcvFrm.pkt.sourcePort;//getClietn port

        char tempData[MAXSIZE];

        if(rcvFrm.type=='R'){
            sprintf(tempData,"%i",ports[portsPtr]);//get new port num
            portsPtr=portsPtr+1; // increment pointer
            pktToSend=createPkt(serverPort,destPort,tempData);
            frmToSend=createFrm(4,'A',0,sourceIP,destIP,pktToSend);

            if((sendto(serverSock,&frmToSend, sizeof(frmToSend),0,(struct sockaddr *)&clientInfo, sockLength))==-1){ //send ACK packet
                perror("\nerror in sending-1 CONF packer: ");
            }//send

            printf("ACK Sent \n");
            fork(); // Here I am creating a new socket to be used with the client and leave the main socket free for other clients
            printf("PORT %i: \n",ports[portsPtr-1]);
            createSocket(ports[portsPtr-1]); // error occurs when call this function. 

        }   

    }//while
}
```

So, the problem is when the server receives `if(rcvFrm.type=='R')`   (new client)
I want to create a new socket to be used for connection with that client and leave the main socket free for other clients. 
I am getting an error when try to create a new socket 
"Error In Binding server Socket: : Address already in use"

I am using `fork()`, so it should create a copy form the code and apply it in different memory locations. And I am trying to create the socket with different port number. Why I am getting an error?

Comment: use "setsockopt"...see man setsockopt..

Comment: Kill all processes that use that socket (locally). Find using `netstat -tulpn`...

Comment: The prompt gives you the answer - figure out why its already in use. Sometimes have to look sideways, though.  I often encounter this when a previous run of the program crashed but continues to exist after having bound a socket, especially when using eclipse.  Also (as mentioned by Maciej, netstat is your friend.

Comment: Thank you. I ll try to do these tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem

```
        fork(); // Here I am creating a new socket to be used with the client and leave the main socket free for other clients
        printf("PORT %i: \n",ports[portsPtr-1]);
        createSocket(ports[portsPtr-1])
```

in this case both parent and child try to create new socket on the same port !!!!

Solution:

```
pid_t  pid;

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) //child
 createSocket(ports[portsPtr-1]);
```

[> fork() returns a zero to the newly created child process.](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)

Thanks